# Case Management System (Ticketing System) - How to?

Tags: database, toolkit

I am looking at developing a simple case management system, a sort of ticketing system where users can enter data in forms, moving from one form to another pressing Next, Next etc.

The information will then be stored in a database, and kept on a case by case basis, will be available for searching and modifications later.

I was thinking about the Microsoft Access Developer toolkit but it seems it is no longer supported and the latest version is 2007.

Can someone suggest some form of tool that I could use please?

Thanks, Noel

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what kind of language knowledge you have and for what platform you are targeting (fat client for windows, Linux etc or web)
There are tons of application development tools

But if would like something similar to access you can give Libreoffice Base a try.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply, at university I was very good in java but it was many years ago and I forgot everything I would have to start from the beginning.

Comment: The platform the application is going to run on is Windows 7 right now, maybe Windows 10 in the future. Back-end database would be Oracle and I am planning to get communication through an ODBC.